# Using table in template

Tags: go

In my GO code, I can `Post` form data to the server as below:

1. Create `struct` to represent the form data
2. Marshal the data into JSON
3. Post JSON data to the server
4. Get server response
5. Convert the server response body into bytes `ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)`
6. Unmarshal  server response body (if in JSON)
7. Handle the response

```golang
// go build -ldflags "-H=windowsgui"
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"
)

// ContactDetails ...
type ContactDetails struct {
    Email   string
    Subject string
    Message string
}

// ReturnedResult ...
type ReturnedResult struct {
    Result  bool   `json:"result"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("forms.html"))
    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
        return
    }

    details := ContactDetails{
        Email:   r.FormValue("email"),
        Subject: r.FormValue("subject"),
        Message: r.FormValue("message"),
    }

    // do something with details
    sheetID := "AKfycbxfMucXOzX15tfU4errRSAa9IzuTRbHzvUdRxzzeYnNA8Ynz8LJuBuaMA/exec"
    url := "https://script.google.com/macros/s/" + sheetID + "/exec"
    bytesRepresentation, err := json.Marshal(details)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    resp, err := http.Post(url, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(bytesRepresentation))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    // read all response body
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    // close response body
    resp.Body.Close()

    webReturn := ReturnedResult{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &webReturn); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(webReturn.Message)

    //tmpl.Execute(w, struct{ Success bool }{webReturn.Result})
    tmpl.Execute(w, webReturn)
}

func main() {
    // Start Host goroutine
    go func() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", index)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
    }()
}
```

The form template I've is below and is working smoothly

```html
<title>Form Submittal</title>
<h1>Contact</h1>
<form method="POST">
    <label>Email:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="email"><br />
    <label>Subject:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="subject"><br />
    <label>Message:</label><br />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea><br />

    <input type="submit">
</form>
{{if .Result}}
    <div id='foo'>
        <a href={{.Message}}>Download PDF file</a>
    </div>
    <h1></h1>
    <script>
        // setTimeout(function () {document.querySelector('#foo').style.display='none'}, 5000);
    </script>
{{end}}
```

Now I've another requirement that needs me to add html5 `table` to the template, so it become:

```html
<title>Form Submittal</title>
<h1>Contact</h1>
<form method="POST">
    <label>Email:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="email"><br />
    <label>Subject:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="subject"><br />
    <label>Message:</label><br />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea><br />

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td><h2>In</h2></td>
            <td><h2>Out</h2></td>
            <td><h2>Total</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>InData</td>
            <td>OutData</td>
            <td>TotalData</td>
        </tr>
</table>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
{{if .Result}}
    <div id='foo'>
        <a href={{.Message}}>Download PDF file</a>
    </div>
    <h1></h1>
    <script>
        // setTimeout(function () {document.querySelector('#foo').style.display='none'}, 5000);
    </script>
{{end}}
```

My question is, what could be the `struct` to be created to handle this form, do I need to modify:

```golang
type ContactDetails struct {
    Email   string
    Subject string
    Message string
}
```

Or what is the best way to handle this table?

**UPDATE**
Below sample of the data required:

```golang
type Payments struct {
    BU                  string
    PONo                string
    PO/PIValue          Number
    Currency            string
    VATrequired?        bool
    POcopyAttachment    attachement
}
```

[image]

Comment: What data do you want to display in the table?

Comment: @Mihai different types I updated my questiion.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. Are you asking about the form or the table? What has one to do with the other? What do you mean by "handle the table"?

Comment: @Peter my problem is how to submit the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your data structure to be a single payment like this

```
type Payment struct {
    BU                  string
    PONo                string
    PO/PIValue          Number
    Currency            string
    VATrequired?        bool
    POcopyAttachment    attachement
}
```

And pass a `[]Payment` to your template. You can then use the [range](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables) action to create your table rows.

Something like this:

```
{{range .Payments}}    
   <tr>
        <td>.BU</td>
        <td>.PONo</td>
        <td>.Currency</td>
        ....
    </tr>
{{end}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is to display the data, my question about data to be entered by the user then be collected and submitted.